# Set TrimBox to geometry's layout area

Tags: luatex, geometry, pdfx, trimbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=10cm
  , paperheight=10cm
  , layoutwidth=5cm
  , layoutheight=5cm
  , layouthoffset=25mm
  , layoutvoffset=25mm
  , includeheadfoot
  , showcrop
}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

If I compile the MWE above, and view the TrimBox of the PDF using a PDF viewer like Acrobat, the TrimBox is not aligned with the crop marks produced by the `geometry` package. (See the image below: the TrimBox as output is in green; it should properly be positioned in line with the pink rectangle.) How can I pass the dimensions and offsets of `layout` to `pdfx` so that it can put the TrimBox in the right place (or else overwrite `pdfx`'s placement of TrimBox)? I'm using LuaTeX.

[image: Actual and desired positions of the TrimBox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pdfx hard codes the trimbox with a border of 25/20 pt. You will have to reset it. Be aware that other packages using the variable pagesattr can interfere (the 0.996264009963 values for /MediaBox are from pdfx).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=10cm
  , paperheight=10cm
  , layoutwidth=5cm
  , layoutheight=5cm
  , layouthoffset=25mm
  , layoutvoffset=25mm
  , includeheadfoot
  , showcrop
}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\tl_new:N\l_soli_trimbox_tl
\tl_set:Nx\l_soli_trimbox_tl 
 {
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{\Gm@layouthoffset}
  \c_space_tl
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{\Gm@layoutvoffset}
  \c_space_tl
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{\paperwidth - \Gm@layouthoffset}
  \c_space_tl
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{\paperheight - \Gm@layoutvoffset}
 }
\tl_new:N\l_soli_mediabox_tl
\tl_set:Nx \l_soli_mediabox_tl 
 {
  0
  \c_space_tl
  0
  \c_space_tl
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{0.996264009963\paperwidth}
  \c_space_tl
  \dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n{0.996264009963\paperheight}
 }

\edef\next
 {
  \pdfvariable~pagesattr
   {
     /MediaBox[\l_soli_mediabox_tl]
     /BleedBox[\l_soli_mediabox_tl]
     /CropBox[\l_soli_mediabox_tl]
     /TrimBox[\l_soli_trimbox_tl]
   }
  } 
 \next
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good, but strangely the resulting TrimBox does not line up with `geometry`'s crop marks (this is hard to see with the current MWE, but can be seen much more clearly if you set e.g. `paper=a3paper`, `layout=a4paper`, and centre the layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGvuG.png). Is this a problem with geometry?

Comment: I didn't really try to check the exact dimensions needed. Perhaps you need to move down/substract line width somewhere.

Comment: Why would that be? Doesn't `geometry` just place `layout` using the same calculations as you used to place the TrimBox? (Well, maybe it is better to have `\Gm@layouthoffset + \Gm@layoutwidth` instead of `\paperwidth - \Gm@layouthoffset` and `\Gm@layoutvoffset + \Gm@layoutheight` instead of `\paperheight - \Gm@layoutvoffset`, in case `layout` is not centred within `paper`.)

Comment: After some research, I have discovered that the discrepancy is created by the fact that LaTeX defines 1 pt = 1/72.27 in, whereas the point is now de facto standardised at 1 pt = 1/72 in. Replacing `\dim_to_decimal:n` with `\dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n` in your answer solves the problem. If you update your answer I am happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: oh, right, good catch. Edited.